# How do you debug win32 com integration from Python?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to call the text to speech API from Python using win32com.client. The Python interpreter is bundled with Splunk and I'm able to invoke it manually using "*splunk cmd python*".

Here's a sample

```
from win32com.client import constants
import win32com.client
speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speaker.Speak('this is a test')
```

My code is invoked via the splunkd process (running as a normal windows user) and I get the following error message.

**(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147200925), None)**

I'm struggling to troubleshoot the problem, any suggestions?

The bundled Python version is
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Feb  7 2011, 14:20:39) [MSC v.1400 64 bit (AMD64)]

Cross-posted from Splunk Answers
http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/31181/debugging-custom-search-commands

== update ==
I've tracked the problem down to the process launching the python interpreter.
For some reason the processes messes with the environment in such a way that the
python interpreter behaves differently. I suspect the win32 error is actually an 
access violation.

Comment: did you tried 32bit python? same results? you can use ollydbg to launch python process and see actually what is the exception (ollydbg only works with 32bit executables) for 64bit you can use windbg (ms debug tools) but is less friendly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application runs as expected when launched as a normal user. The parent process runs as system, which fails to invoke the TTS.